# Query through linked server is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have 2 SQL 2005 servers SRV1 and SRV2. SRV2 is the linked server on SRV1. I run a stored proc with params on SRV2 and it is completed immediately. But when I run the same proc through the linked server on SRV1, for example  EXEC [SRV1].DB_TEST.dbo.p_sample_proc it takes about 8-10 minutes to complete. After restarting SRV2 the problem is gone. But some time later it returns. Does anyone have any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Might need more rights on SRV2, says [Linchi Shea in this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/07/21/performance-impact-linked-server-security-configuration-and-how-it-can-hurt-you.aspx)

The login used need to run `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`

Edit: After andomar's comment: what does this do?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ('SRV1', 'EXEC DB_TEST.dbo.p_sample_proc')
```

Comment: SRV1 doesn't need SRV2's statistics if it's calling a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, check Management -> Activity Monitor on SRV2.   That should show you the state of the process that's running p_sample_proc.  Maybe it is blocking on a lock from some other process.

It's safe to say that resetting a server removes all locks, and maybe the blocking application takes a while to reconnect to SRV2.